# Horizontal stretch list item in WP7 with grouping

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to implement ListBox Grouping on WP7. I found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/03/17/confessions-of-a-listbox-groupie-using-ivalueconverter-to-create-a-grouped-list-of-items-simply-and-flexibly.aspx) is very useful. Actually I made the grouping works. But I got a problem with ListItem horizontal stretch. I guess I need to set ItemContainerStyle and change HorizontalContentAlignment as Stretch. But it doesn't work for this case (if set the ItemTemplate directly, it works). Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Here is the code, the ListItem is supposed to be stretched, but it's centered instead.

C#:

```
public class GroupingItemsControlConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type tagetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var valueAsIEnumerable = value as IEnumerable;
        if (null == valueAsIEnumerable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("GroupingItemsControlConverter works for only IEnumerable inputs.", "value");
        }
        var parameterAsGroupingItemsControlConverterParameter = parameter as GroupingItemsControlConverterParameters;
        if (null == parameterAsGroupingItemsControlConverterParameter)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Missing required GroupingItemsControlConverterParameter.", "parameter");
        }
        var groupSelectorAsIGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector = parameterAsGroupingItemsControlConverterParameter.GroupSelector as IGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector;
        if (null == groupSelectorAsIGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("GroupingItemsControlConverterParameter.GroupSelector must be non-null and implement IGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector.", "parameter");
        }

        // Return the grouped results
        return ConvertAndGroupSequence(valueAsIEnumerable.Cast<object>(), parameterAsGroupingItemsControlConverterParameter);
    }

    private IEnumerable<object> ConvertAndGroupSequence(IEnumerable<object> sequence, GroupingItemsControlConverterParameters parameters)
    {
        // Validate parameters
        var groupKeySelector = ((IGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector)(parameters.GroupSelector)).GetGroupKeySelector();
        var orderKeySelector = ((IGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector)(parameters.GroupSelector)).GetOrderKeySelector();
        if (null == groupKeySelector)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("IGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector.GetGroupSelector must return a non-null value.");
        }

        // Do the grouping and ordering
        var groupedOrderedSequence = sequence.GroupBy(groupKeySelector).OrderBy(orderKeySelector);

        // Return the wrapped results
        foreach (var group in groupedOrderedSequence)
        {
            yield return new ContentControl { Content = group.Key, ContentTemplate = parameters.GroupStyle };
            foreach (var item in group)
            {
                yield return new ContentControl { Content = item, ContentTemplate = parameters.ItemStyle };
            }
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type tagetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("GroupingItemsControlConverter does not support ConvertBack.");
    }
}

public class GroupingItemsControlConverterParameters
{
    public DataTemplate GroupStyle { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ItemStyle { get; set; }
    public IGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector GroupSelector { get; set; }
};

public abstract class IGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector
{
    public abstract Func<object, IComparable> GetGroupKeySelector();
    public virtual Func<IGrouping<IComparable, object>, IComparable> GetOrderKeySelector() { return g => g.Key; }
}

public class GroupingItemsControlConverterSelector : IGroupingItemsControlConverterSelector
{
    public override Func<object, IComparable> GetGroupKeySelector()
    {
        return (o) => (o as ItemViewModel).Group;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupHeaderTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="1" Margin="12,3,12,12" Padding="6" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomItemTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="12,3,12,12" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="White"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,0" FontSize="22" Foreground="White"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:GroupingItemsControlConverter x:Key="GroupingItemsConverter" />
        <local:GroupingItemsControlConverterSelector x:Key="GroupingItemsSelector" />
        <local:GroupingItemsControlConverterParameters x:Key="GroupingItemParameters" 
                                                       GroupStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTemplate}" 
                                                       ItemStyle="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}" 
                                                       GroupSelector="{StaticResource GroupingItemsSelector}"
                                                       />

        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="CustomItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListBox x:Name="TheListBox" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Converter={StaticResource GroupingItemsConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource GroupingItemParameters}}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomItemContainerStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` to the border in the group template and to the grid in the item template?

Comment: Yes, i have tried and the [way](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/d93281f3-d369-45b9-ae50-ce273941f959) which is mentioned by Peter Torr. Both didn't work. I guess can write some C# code to force computer the list item width as its parent, but haven't try that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListBox grouping? You should consider using the LongListSelector from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). And to simplify the binding for that, you can use the [LongListCollection](https://bitbucket.org/Windcape/diverse/src/d6d90d3fa45e/LongListSample/LongListCollection.cs) collection type (Check the [entire example](https://bitbucket.org/Windcape/diverse/src/d6d90d3fa45e/LongListSample/), for details).

Then you can simply create apps that groups values, for example like this:

[image: longlistselector grouping]

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I have looked into your sample code. It seems that the stretch problem is still existing. Do you have any ways to make the GroupHeader stretch in the list? Thanks!

Comment: Modifying the the equivalent of the ItemContainerStyle , as you said in your original question, should do this just fine.

Comment: it looks like i am using an old version of toolkit, with new version the problem is fixed. thank you for help out!

Comment: Did you use the LLS with a specified header? It doesn't allow to scroll itself to the bottom in that case.